# Populate DropDownList in ASP.NET MVC from database table using Entity Framework 6 and ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, viewmodel, dropdownlistfor

I have been scratching my head for a whole night on an issue I can do quickly using ajax/jquery and stored procedures. I want to

1) Populate a drop down list from values obtained from a database table using Entity Framework and view model. I DO NOT WANT TO USE VIEWBAG OR VIEWDATA. Any help appreciated.

2) How can I generate a Create View using the View Model with the all the default fields ? The scaffholding works on a model but not on a view model ?

**MY MODELS**

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Level { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
}

public class Grade
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Level { get; set; }
}
```

**View Model**

```
public class GradeSelectListViewModel
{

    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Grades { get; set; }
    public GradeSelectListViewModel(Employee employee, IEnumerable grades)
    {
        Employee = employee;
        Grades = new SelectList(grades, "Grade", "Name", employee.Level);
    }
}
```

**MY CONTEXT CLASS**

```
public class EmployeeContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Grade> Grades { get; set; }
}
```

**MY CONTROLLER**

```
public ActionResult Edit (int? id)
{
    using (var db = new EmployeeContext())
    {
        var model = new GradeSelectListViewModel(db.Employees.Find(id), db.Grades);
        //model.Employee = db.Employees.Single(x => x.EmployeeID == id);
        model.Grades = db.Grades.ToList().Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.ID.ToString(),
            Text = x.Level
        });
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

MY RAZOR PAGE CSHTML

```
@model MVCDemo.ViewModels.GradeSelectListViewModel
....
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    ....
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.Employee.Level,
        new SelectList(Model.Grades, "ID", "Level"),
        "Select Level")
    ....
    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

Comment: Its just `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.Employee.Level, Model.Grades, "Select Level")`. But there are other issues with your code. A view model should not contain a data model. You need to delete the constructor in `GradeSelectListViewModel` (or add a parameterless constructor). You do not need `.ToList()` in `db.Grades.ToList()....`

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I did the changes you requested. I'm getting null reference  on dropdownlist when I do Employees/Create    : System.NullReferenceException:                                                         Ligne 16 :             <div class=" ="form-group">
Ligne 17 :                 <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
Ligne 18 :                     @Html.DropDownListFor(
Ligne 19 :             x => Model.Employee.Level,
Ligne 20 :             Model.Grades,

Comment: What are the details of the message? Your code shows you populate  `model.Grades` so it cannot be `null` if you have returned the model to the view

Comment: The method you have shown is `Edit()`  - but that error relates to a method named `Create()` :)

Comment: Yes, the action is Edit, sorry. Nearly getting it. Now it says . The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed, when I make Employees/Edit/1 . The employee with id 1 exists already.

Comment: That's because you assigning it in a `using` statement. If you want that then use `model.Grades = db.Grades..Select(...).AsEnumerable();`

Comment: Thanks Stephen ! it works. I like to dispose of my connection but here I had to do it like that. Got same issue with AsEnumerable. Did it like that                  public ActionResult Edit (int? id)
        {
            var db = new EmployeeContext();
                var model = new GradeSelectListViewModel();
                model.Grades = db.Grades.Select(x => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = x.ID.ToString(),
                    Text = x.Level
                });
                return View(model);
        }

Comment: How can I mark your answer as the correct one ?

Comment: Yes, that is the best way. Bit busy at the moment, but I'll add an answer in about an hour with a few other notes as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main issue is that in the view you have `new SelectList(Model.Grades, "ID", "Level")` but `Grades` is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and `SelectListItem` does not contain properties named `ID` and `Level`.

However there are a a few other issues with your code. First a view model should not contain a data model, and instead your view model should be

```
public class GradeSelectListViewModel
{
    public int? ID { get; set; } // make this ID so you do not need an input for it
    public string Name { get; set; }
    .... // other properties of Employee that your editing
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "..")]
    public int? Level { get; set; } // make value types nullable to protect against under-posting attacks
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Grades { get; set; }
}
```

and add display and validation attributes as required. Note that I deleted the constructor (you don't seem to be using it, but if you did, then you also need to include a parameter-less constructor, otherwise an exception will be thrown when submitting to the POST method. I also assume that `Level` should be typeof `int` since you binding to the `int ID` property of `Grade`.

The the code in your GET method should be

```
Employee employee = db.Employees.Find(id);
var model = new GradeSelectListViewModel()
{
    ID = employee.EmployeeID,
    Name = employee.Name,
    Level = employee.Level, // convert to int?
    ....
    Grades = db.Grades.Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = x.ID.ToString(),
        Text = x.Level
    })
};
return View(model);
```

and in the view

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.Level, Model.Grades, "Select Level")
```

Note also that in the POST method, your need to reassign the `SelectList` if you return the view because `ModelState` is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following approach that populates three DropDownListFor at the same View:

**ViewModel:**

```
public class GroupViewModel
{  
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Schedules { get; set; }
    public int ScheduleId { get; set; }
 
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Labs { get; set; }
    public int LabId { get; set; }
 
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Terms { get; set; } 
    public int TermId { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    //Populate DropDownList binding values
    var model = new GroupViewModel
    {
        //Preselect the Lab with id 2
        //LabId = 2,
 
        Labs = repository.Labs.Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = c.Id.ToString(),
            Text = c.Name
        }),
        Terms = repository.Terms.Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = c.Id.ToString(),
            Text = c.Name
        }),
        Schedules = repository.Schedules.Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = c.Id.ToString(),
            Text = c.Name
        })
    };
    return View("Create", model);
}
```

**View:**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.LabId, new SelectList(Model.Labs, "Value", "Text"), 
    "Select", new { @class = "selectpicker" })
 
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ScheduleId, new SelectList(Model.Schedules, "Value", "Text"), 
    "Select", new { @class = "selectpicker" })
                                
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TermId, new SelectList(Model.Terms, "Value", "Text"), 
    "Select", new { @class = "selectpicker" })
```