# MVC 5 C# Javascript Event to Select Data and populate text boxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have 2 models with a foreign Key, TblConfig is the Parent and TblStock is the Child. How can I write a Javascript event or server side script. when I click on a button on Stock View Create, TblConfig  appears I select the product I want and it polulates the Stock View Textboxes i.e ID, Name and Price and leave one Textbox empty where I'll put stock. I can do it very easy on c# standalone using the "onclick event" but on web MVC I have no idea!!

this is my  first Question someone please help me with the answer.

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42549622/populate-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc-from-database-table-using-entity-framework

Comment: Thanks for the link but Populating a dropdown list, I can do that. My issue is selecting data and populate text boxes

Comment: listen to the click event, make an ajax call to get the data, update the input element.  I suggest you start trying it.

Comment: First step what I did I created a Partial View in modal and it's working fine. so I have My table on my partial view and the text boxes on the parent page. when I click on the table it's populating the text boxes but the when I click another row it's not changing the values ? how can You assist